# recursively copying and renaming file works, then stopped unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file-rename, file-copying

#### Context

1. Needed to copy and rename image file repeatedly until certain counting number reached.
2. The renaming part have to met certain increasing step.
3. It's `Python 3.7.0`

#### Code

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

fps = 30
timer = 1 #in seconds
count = fps * timer + 1

#input and output file directory
src1 = glob.glob("./src/captured1.jpg")
dest = "./dst/"

#numbering start from 1 with increasing step of 4
for i in range(1,count,4):
    for file_path in src1:
        print(file_path)
        shutil.copy(file_path, dest)
        for filename in os.listdir(dest):
            os.rename(os.path.join(dest,filename), os.path.join(dest,'image'+ str(i) + '.jpg'))
```

#### Output

Expecting the images will have sequentially numbered name (i.e image1.jpg image5.jpg image9.jpg and so on)

#### Problem

Code worked up until image9.jpg, then stopped in the middle of traceback with error of :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\home\user\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    os.rename(os.path.join(dest,filename), os.path.join(dest,'captured'+ str(i) + '.jpg'))
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: './dst/image5.jpg' -> './dst/image9.jpg'
```

How can I improve the code?

Comment: From what I can see, you have a problem because the images aren't counted from 0, so you should just check for the last numbered image, get it's name, from that get it's number and continue renaming from that number

Comment: The problem is in the inner for loop. You take each file and try to rename it to the same filename.

Comment: @ack aren't the looped `str(i)` supposed to take care of that already?

Comment: Inside the `for filename in os.listdir(dest):`loop `i` does not change.